# Speed up search query that searches in post meta?

Tags: query, search, sql

I have a rather big query I'm executing (due to clients request). The original search was super slow due to inclusion of WPML tables, so I used `posts_clauses` filter to create this query

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID =wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE 1=1
  AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%string%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%string%') OR (wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%string%'))
  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('page', 'post', 'cpt')
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN wp_posts.post_type = 'page' THEN '1'
                WHEN wp_posts.post_type = 'cpt' THEN '2'
                WHEN wp_posts.post_type = 'post' THEN '3'
          ELSE wp_posts.post_type END ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 12
```

Since I have over 250k entries in the postmeta table and over 1000 in the post table, when I run this query in my db (phpmyadmin) it's over 1 second, and on the staging server in the query monitor it takes over 2 seconds to run it. To see the results I am waiting over 5 seconds.

Is there any way to improve performance of this query? Will increasing server resources help?

EDIT:

`EXPLAIN` gives:

```
id    select_type    table       type     possible_keys       key                key_len    ref                   rows    Extra
1     SIMPLE         wp_posts    range    type_status_date    type_status_date   82         NULL    1             159     Using index condition; Using temporary; Using file...
1     SIMPLE         wp_postmeta ref      post_id             post_id            8          db_table.wp_posts.ID  23      Using where; Distinct
```

Comment: Can you use `EXPLAIN` to see what is happening? You could also Remove the `Order by` if this is not needed it.

Comment: Order by is important I'm afraid. I'll post the `EXPLAIN` results in the post